# Passing parameters from html script to js file

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I am aware this has already been asked many different ways but I could not find solution in any of the answers... So I figured I would supply my exact problem:

this is the html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idArray = <?php json_encode($idArray) ?>;
    var imgArray = <?php json_encode($imgArray) ?>;
    var prArray = <?php json_encode($prArray) ?>;
</script>
```

and then I would like to use those 3 arrays in my "script.js" file.
here is the idea:

```
var idArray = AnActualVarFromHtmlScript.idArray;
var imgArray = AnActualVarFromHtmlScript.imgArray;
var prArray = AnActualVarFromHtmlScript.prArray;
```

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: You don't need to "redeclare" your `vars`. You can use it directly. When you declare it like you did in HTML, it's declared implicitly in `window` variable. The only thing you should be aware is to declare your variables in html part before including your js file.

Comment: By using `var idArray` in your script, you're shadowing the global variable `idArray`. Simply don't do that…!?

Comment: @deceze im sorry but i dont understand your comment? dont do what? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined in your html between scripts-tags will be registered on the `window`-scope. Therefore you can access those variables with `window.idArray` instead of `AnActualVarFromHtmlScript.idArray`.

Comment: Cheers :) helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in order to make those values really exist your php should "echo" them, but I would mix PHP and HTML rather than PHP and JS.

This should be better.
You can use the "data" attribute(jQuery, for example, brings you a 'data' function to do it) to store values you need into HTML elements:

```html
<ul class="img-list" data-images="[1,2,3,4,5]">
</ul>
```

Then you can retrieve it this way:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.img-list');
console.log(el.getAttribute('data-images'));
```

Another way you can achieve it(since you're JSON encoding your php output), is to deal with AJAX requests and let your JS use the response.

Hope it was useful!